# Multiple servlet-mappings in web.xml on IBM WAS

Tags: web-services, servlets, web.xml, ibm-was, servlet-mapping

My web service module is accessed by multiple customers having different clients and should, therefore, be accessible by different URIs, like

```
[serverAddress]/MyHTTPRouter/PingService
```

and

```
[serverAddress]/MyHTTPRouter/cet/PingService
```

(replace [serverAddress] with myorg.com or localhost... sorry for that, but StackOverflow limits me currently to two links (even http://localhost counts))

So, I wanted to define 2 servlet-mappings in my web.xml. On StackOverflow, I found the following hints:
a) [Servlet web.xml servlet-mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746360/servlet-web-xml-servlet-mapping)
b) [How are Servlet url mappings in web.xml used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385596/servlet-mapping-web-xml)

I did the following attempts:

**Try #1:**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myorg.PingServiceImpl</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myorg.PingServiceImpl</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/cet/PingService</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/PingService</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Test result with SoapUI:

1. **[serverAddress]/MyHTTPRouter/PingService :** ok
2. **[serverAddress]/MyHTTPRouter/cet/PingService :** Error 404: java.io.FileNotFoundException: WSWS7147E: The system could not
   locate the endpoint for /cet/PingService.

**Try #2:**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myorg.PingServiceImpl</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myorg.PingServiceImpl</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/PingService</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myorg.PingServiceImpl</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/cet/PingService</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Test result with SoapUI:

1. **[serverAddress]/MyHTTPRouter/PingService :**  Error 500:
   javax.servlet.ServletException:
   com.ibm.ws.websvcs.exception.ConfigurationException: Could not
   retrieve configuration context in Axis servlet for module:
   MyHTTPRouter
2. **[serverAddress]/MyHTTPRouter/cet/PingService :** same as above (Error
   500)

We're talking about an EJB 3.1 application running on IBM Websphere Application Server 8.5.
Any ideas why both #1 and #2 are not working and what changes I need to do to access the web service with both /cet/PingService and /PingService ?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue ? please post your solution if you have one.

Comment: i'm trying resolve this issue for 5 days. Couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts @JToddler, we could not find out the reason or a solution in code / xml. Finally, the infra team defined a junction in WebSEAL, but I don't know the details.